# Zero Sized Reply. Squid did not receive any data for this request

Tags: wordpress, civicrm-home

When working in various set up stages of CiviCRM, a new member page or contributions page I often get this error message:

> The requested URL could not be retrieved
>   While trying to retrieve the URL:....
>   The following error was encountered:
>   Zero Sized Reply.
>   Squid did not receive any data for this request.

Is this only because WordPress failed to auto update? Is this something only my Cache Admin can solve?

Comment: I use varnish instead of squid as a front-end proxy, but I've had similar issues from time to time. You'll want to check quite a few server logs for hints (php, http, and squid). It might be as simple as a timeout error, or it might be more subtle involving a php configuration.